# Can you write a contract which bytecode can be proven that can only send ether to a given address?

Tags: contract-development, assembly

I'm thinking maybe looking through the OP codes, you can realize that the contract can only send money to a given address. Would this kind of formal verification be hard to write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is rather easy I think, even with solidity

```
contract Example{

address recipient = 0x0000cafebabe;

function send(){
    recipient.send(this.balance);
 }
}
```

results in (optimized bytecode):

```
606060405260008054600160a060020a03191663cafebabe178155604e908190602790396000f3606060405260e060020a6000350463b46300ec8114601a575b005b60186000805473ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff9081169190301631606082818181858883f1505050505056
```

etherscan.io can disassemble the bytecode once it is on the mainnet or use `disasm' [form the geth tools](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Ubuntu)

```
    echo "606060405260008054600160a060020a03191663cafebabe178155604e908190602790396000f3606060405260e060020a6000350463b46300ec8114601a575b005b60186000805473ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff9081169190301631606082818181858883f1505050505056" | disasm
```

Gives back:

```
0      PUSH1  => 60
2      PUSH1  => 40
4      MSTORE
5      PUSH1  => 00
7      DUP1
8      SLOAD
9      PUSH1  => 01
11     PUSH1  => a0
13     PUSH1  => 02
15     EXP
16     SUB
17     NOT
18     AND
19     PUSH4  => cafebabe
24     OR
25     DUP2
26     SSTORE
27     PUSH1  => 4e
29     SWAP1
30     DUP2
31     SWAP1
32     PUSH1  => 27
34     SWAP1
35     CODECOPY
36     PUSH1  => 00
38     RETURN
39     PUSH1  => 60
41     PUSH1  => 40
43     MSTORE
44     PUSH1  => e0
46     PUSH1  => 02
48     EXP
49     PUSH1  => 00
51     CALLDATALOAD
52     DIV
53     PUSH4  => b46300ec
58     DUP2
59     EQ
60     PUSH1  => 1a
62     JUMPI
63     JUMPDEST
64     STOP
65     JUMPDEST
66     PUSH1  => 18
68     PUSH1  => 00
70     DUP1
71     SLOAD
72     PUSH20  => ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
93     SWAP1
94     DUP2
95     AND
96     SWAP2
97     SWAP1
98     ADDRESS
99     AND
100    BALANCE
101    PUSH1  => 60
103    DUP3
104    DUP2
105    DUP2
106    DUP2
107    DUP6
108    DUP9
109    DUP4
110    CALL
111    POP
112    POP
113    POP
114    POP
115    POP
116    JUMP
```

Comment: In the bytecode, what is the part which sends the money?

Comment: `.send` is implemented with `CALL` opcode (byte 110 in this example).